# Knowing all status of a Job with Kotlin coroutines

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions

Is it possible to know all the status of a coroutine Job ?

I find this function extension but I can't access to all the status of a `Job` :

```
fun Job.status(): String = when {
    isCancelled -> "cancelled"
    isActive -> "Active"
    isCompleted -> "Complete"
    else -> "Nothing"
}
```

There is no `isNew`, `isCancelling` or `isWaitingForChildren` functions with the `Job` classe. Why ?

[image]

Comment: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/

Comment: I wonder why would you need it? For debugging you can just print `job.toString()`. If you have some real use-case to get the status, then can you please explain it in a separate issue at https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines

Comment: It's just for a better understanding of the Job cyclelife. Just learning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Drawn Roccoon I found the solution :

```
fun Job.status(): String = when {
    isActive -> "Active/Completing"
    isCompleted && isCancelled -> "Cancelled"
    isCancelled -> "Cancelling"
    isCompleted -> "Completed"
    else -> "New"
}
```

[image]

More information in this link : https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/

Comment: You can minimize this, first row is just `isActive` and then the rest of the clauses don't need to check `isActive` at all. On the other hand, the code is open to races because you can't read the flags atomically. For example, you may paradoxically get the status "New" for a completed job.

Comment: `isCancelled -> "Cancelling"` --- i believe this is wrong since you assume `!isCompleted` without checking it. Also, you could at least lower the odds of race conditions by reading the flags just once, before `when`. It would still not remove the problem.